# Что это? GIT, 5000 файлов

Tags: git

Скачал GIT, настроил имя и почту, захожу в VSCode, подключился GIT и откуда то взял 5000 файлов, что это?
Или возможно так и должно быть?
[image: GIT 5000 и 1 файл]

Comment: Вы, видимо, сделали `git init` в корне своей пользовательской папки (но это не точно).

Comment: Видимо вы контроль версий подключили не к проекту а папке пользователя windows. Вот он за ней и следит. Проверьте в C:\Users\Пользователь есть скрытая папка .git ?

Comment: Да, вы правы, это можно как-то исправить?

Comment: Удалите папку .git и сделайте `git init` в папке с проектом. Папка в консоли меняется с помощью команды `cd`

Comment: Помогло,разобрался

Comment: В общем у кого такая-же проблема, для начала через панель управления требуется сделать отображение скрытых файлов, затем в домашней директории найти файл .git и удалить его, затем в рабочем проекте прописать git init и все.

Comment: @MrSilentBeast, чтобы это было полезно не только Вам ,но и тем ,кто столкнется с подобной проблемой, было бы лучше ,если бы Вы оформили свой комментарий как ответ.

Answer (score 1):

В общем у кого такая-же проблема, для начала:

1. Через панель управления требуется сделать отображение скрытых файлов.
2. Затем в домашней директории найти файл **.git** и удалить его.
3. Затем в рабочем проекте прописать `git init` и все

> Чтобы решение было полезно не только Вам ,но и тем ,кто столкнется с
> подобной проблемой, было бы лучше ,если бы Вы оформили свой
> комментарий как ответ.  [@Юрий Козлов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/330321/%D0%AE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2)

Красиво и понятно оформите ответ, сохраните и нажмите галочку "Правильный ответ". Так же вы можете ставить рейтинг на ответ нажав стрелку "Вверх" + или "Вниз" -.